# VS Code and Typescript watch: Files are being recompiled without being saved

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, watch, tsconfig

I'm developing a Typescript project and I run "tsc -w" to keep it compiling while I edit.

The problem is, sometimes my files will be recompiled even when I don't save them. Sometimes it recompiles files randomly that I haven't touched (Like if I open an existing file in typescript to begin editing)

Is this vs code? or Typescript? does anyone know a solution to stop this happening?

My .tsconfig is below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": [ "src/shared/*" ],
      "@app/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "types": [
    "react",
    "react-dom",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "jest.config.js",
    "App.js"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src",
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: what's bad about the recompilation? TypeScript definitely has reasons for that, but the question is how does it bother you?

Comment: I run both tsc -w and another process (expo start) which picks up those changes and sends them as hot code replacements to my React Native app. Sometimes this causes the app to restart itself. I don't understand why the app restarts if the file hasn't actually changed (just recompiled) or is a valid hot code replacement, but this wouldn't occur if typescript only compiled the files when I intend them to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have to run a separate Typescript Watch process - Expo Typescript support has improved since I started my project.

See https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/typescript/